# create package create package body record data type

Tags: oracle, package, procedure

i have an existing package named "fusion". The package definition goes like

```
create or replace package "fusion' as
create procedure first_procedure(abc in number)
create procedure second_procedure(efg in number)
end fusion;
```

The package body definition is like

```
create or replace package body fusion as
procedure first_procedure(abc in number) is
begin
....
end first_procedure;
procedure second_procedure(efg in number) is
begin
....
end second_procedure;
end fusion;
```

In this existing package i need to include a third procedure which has a custom record type as output. So where should i declare the custom record type? i have written like

```
create or replace package "fusion' as
type finalrecord is record(column1 varchar2,column2 number);
type mytable is table of finalrecord;
create procedure first_procedure(abc in number)
create procedure second_procedure(efg in number)
create procedure third_procedure(mt out mytable)
end fusion;
```

and package body as

```
create or replace package body fusion as
procedure first_procedure(abc in number) is
begin
....
end first_procedure;
procedure second_procedure(efg in number) is
begin
....
end second_procedure;
procedure third_procedure(mt out mytable) is
myissueid number(2);
begin
--do something
end third_procedure;
end fusion;
```

This is compiling in SQLDeveloper but showing these errors

1. subprogram or cursor 'third_procedure' is declared in a package specification and must be defined in the package body.
2. mytable should be declared

Comment: The updated package specification you show has several errors, but it isn't clear if you've introduced those in changing the code for posting here. [It works when cleaned up a bit](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9bee6/1). Assuming you did change it, you do seem to have recompiled the updated spec before the updated body, but did it say there were errors in the spec? If it was clean then do you have the type and parameter names exactly the same?

Answer (score 0):

Try compiling the Procedure Specification with this update code

```
create or replace package fusion as
type finalrecord is record(column1 varchar2(20),column2 number);
type mytable is table of finalrecord;
procedure first_procedure(abc in number);
procedure second_procedure(efg in number);
procedure third_procedure(mt out mytable);
end fusion;
/
```